# How can I move the footer margin in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

I want to reduce the footer margin to match the header margin.
The problem is that it's not possible to lower the line #2 - it's the Print Preview in Excel 2013). I'm making something wrong?

[image]

Comment: I've tried. I can change the margins of the page, but not the margin of the footer. I set it to 0 but it's stuck there (as you can see from the image)

Comment: In Design tab there's no "Footer from Bottom:" value. Where I can find it?

Comment: That is Word. I'm talking about Excel. In Excel there's no such option!